# iframes and javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a simple webpage that used a include html file as the left navigation. Here is the code for each button:

```
<tr><td id="tdIndex" onmouseout="javascript:DoMouseOut(this)" onmouseover="javascript:DoMouseOver(this)"
class="menuDefault" onclick="javascript:NavPage('All_Rooms_Today.html');">All Rooms Overview</td></tr>
```

Here is the iFrame code on the parent page:

```
<iframe src="All_Rooms_Today.html" style="width: 100%; height: 500px" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0">
</iframe>
```

I need to write the javascript function navpage to populate the `iframe`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do what the `target` attribute does in links?

Comment: yes, I just want the left navigation to poplulate the middle of the parent page which has an iframe. The navigation bar is it's own html page that is an 'include' file.

Answer (score 0):

No need for JavaScript.

```
<a href="All_Rooms_Today.html" target="name_of_frame">All Rooms Overview</a>

<iframe name="name_of_frame" …>
```

You can almost certainly replace all the mouseover/out stuff with:

```
#some_container a {
    display: block;
}

#some_container a:hover {
    background: foo;
    color: bar;
}
```

If you can't, then you should certainly remove the string `javascript:` as there is no use in having [a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) at that point (if you think it means "This is JavaScript", then you're wrong, for intrinsic event attributes [you do that with a meta element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.1)).

For that matter, frames are a pain for bookmarking and for search engines (among other things). You're already using includes, you should probably keep using them and have proper pages including the navigation instead of framed pages.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work for me. The file that has the code to change the parent page that has the iframe is an include file, so it's own html page. I know what I am doing is simple, just forgot how.